# is there a way I can see the address locations of functions and syscalls. any function/or syscall and view specific file in GDB. -- vmlinuz

Tags: c, debugging, linux-kernel, gdb

i want to view the address locations of kernel functions in vmlinuz binary file in kernel code binary.
And also browse throught specific file in linux kernel and debug it. (I am not asking for how to debug but how to list different files and view function addresses and find address locations and with the help of address location debug the function of running kernel) Is there a way for it.

Please note. I know that I will need gdb on different system. I am just asking for If I can connect through usb and connect two computers and debug running kernel.

Thanks for any info and command

Comment: The `System.map` files in `/boot/` should show addresses of some kernel symbols/functions.

Comment: @wxz can I debug kernel with gdb on same system If I get the addresses from `System.map`

Comment: I've never actually used a debugger for the kernel before (I'm not opposed to it although Linus has expressed strong feelings against). Maybe looking into [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/dev-tools/kgdb.html) might help. You could also ask on a Linux kernel mailing list for help.